# GWT: update css fails

Tags: css, gwt

I have a weird GWT problem and I hope somebody can help me. I developed my user-interface by using a Composite-Component and add some manual HTML-code. This code will be styled with a css-file.

css-snippet:

```
#twitterVis{
    position:relative;
    background-color:yellow;
    overflow:visible;
}

#emmVis{
    position:relative;
    background-color:yellow;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

I stored the css in the war-folder and included it in the *.gwt.xml file.

When I try to run the application, then the css code will be merged with the old css styles, which were defined like the following:

```
#emmVis{
    background-color:#888888;
    overflow:scroll;
    width:100%;
    height:95%
}
```

You can see the problem either in the file: war/applicatioName/....cache.html:

```
#emmVis{background-color:yellow;width:100%;height:95%;background-color:#888;overflow:scroll;}
```

or also in the inspector, when using Chrome:

[image]

I'm sure the old css-code is not longer available (I searched through the whole project) and I also

- re-compiled the project
- deleted the *.cache.html files
- cleaned and refreshed the project

But the error is still the same. If I open my interface with the GWT-Designer, everything is fine. So I assume, there is problem with a cache in GWT.

Does somebody has an idea or should I place the files not within the war-folder?

Comment: clear browser cache, then try again.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I already cleared the browser cache. As you can see in the war/applicatioName/....cache.html file, the problem is already before the application has been started. (The problem exist on both, Chrome and Firefox.)

Comment: Were the old css styles stored in the same file as the new styles ?

Comment: First they were stored in the same file and I just changed the parameters. But afterwards I tried to put them in a new file and delete the content from the old file.

Comment: Can you post the content of your *.gwt.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. Clear the browser cache, project clean in eclipse or re-compile didn't work for me. After I renamed the CSS File and updated the reference in the *.gwt.xml file, the changes in the CSS file were loaded successfully.